# How to Uninstall a Device with Powershell

Tags: powershell

So here is the situation to make sure it's well understood.

I have 2 HP packages that I need to install on Windows 10 systems to have the Function Keys reacting properly (for Example Brightness up-down etc).

As a good practice we always create our script with Install / Uninstall option.

One of the package is a simple HP Service Framework this is an Easy Install / Uninstall.

The second package is actually drivers for the keyboard and I cannot see it as an app (so cannot be easily uninstalled). It's only updating the drivers on the computer, so the Generic Keyboard becomes the HP Keyboard.

I found how to remove the Driver package on the computer, so this way once I can uninstall the keyboard it won't reinstall with that driver, but take the default PS2 drivers.

```
$oemfiles = Get-ChildItem c:\windows\inf\oem*.inf
foreach($file in $oemfiles){
    if(get-content $file | select-string -pattern 'hpkeyboard' -SimpleMatch)
        {PnPUtil /Delete-Driver $file.name /force }
}
```

So now that I did that, how can I uninstall the actual device.
(As if I would go in Device Manager and Right Click Uninstall the Keyboard).

PnPUtil only removes the package from Windows.
Disable-PNPDevice, well I don't want to disable it, I want to remove it from the system so it goes back to the Default Keyboard.

If you are asking why I want to remove the Device completely, is that if you leave this keyboard there, the Function keys are looking for the HP Software Framework and gives a constant error message if you press on the key. (Which is anoying).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to the drawing board, and found out I was using and older solution to do what I was required to...

After starting from the beginning and doing a deeper research I found how to run the script I required and found the proper uninstall method!

I guess after look for a few hours there is no appropriate ways of playing with Devices from scripts